# change lyx paragraph display style in UI

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

this is akin to [Can I change the paragraph spacing in LyX UI?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88839/can-i-change-the-paragraph-spacing-in-lyx-ui) but with a slightly different slant.

Like that question I am just trying to change the display, not the typesetting. IN LyX in both article and koma-script article the default style for paragraph is bold. I can change the output with **\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalfont}**, but the screen continues to display bold.
What changes would need to be made to the local layout settings to fix this?

cheers

Comment: Maybe Help → Customization → subsection 5.3.7 and good luck? But worth the effort? Deal with layouts is not a trivial task,  and any way LyX never pretended to be a  "what you see is what you get" (WYSIWYG) program, but a "what you see is what you mean" (WYSIWYM) interface, so the paragraph header in LyX also breaks the line, there are no margins, etc., so never will be near to true preview. Maybe what you are searching is Bakoma, but it is commercial.

Comment: Sure Im not after wysiwyg, Im just after not horrible to read.I am using a hack for numbered paragraphs. I either need an ERT \paragraph{} before every para or set it as a paragraph section. Im not after super pretty but reading 20 pages set in bold is wearying to the eye....

Comment: 20 pages set in bold? Maybe  you apply "Paragraph" (i.e., `\paragraph{}`)  to  the whole paragraphs?  The command is only to make a short inline title (two or three words) followed  by  "Standard" text. i.e., the true paragraph is what is after that command, not inside it. If the main point is numbering normal paragraph, consider   the numbered lists.

Comment: Sorry I am confusing things. The final document is a legal report which requires *every single* paragraph to be numbered. There are a number of hacks to support that. The simplest is to set the body text as a paragraph and take the auto numbering in Lyx down to paragraph. Works, but ugly for reading and editing on screen. A different hack looks nicer but need ERT as above. Just wondering if I can have my cake and eat it. If not then will likely go with the ERT hack

Comment: Edit your question to paste a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your .lyx  file  (or better, the .tex version).   Without see the whole picture (e.g., whether the document have sections) and explain all your requirements  (whether the paragraph number should inherit the section numbers, whether it should be reset after section, if numbers should be in the margin or the text area, etc.) will be hard guess if you may want  some other approach.